# dd speed issue using ibs/obs

Tags: perl, command-line, dd

I have a loop where I use dd to copy a stream to a disk. I am using a larger blocksize using 'bs' in the entire process for speed reasons. However with one specific line I have to use 'ibs' and 'obs' because my 'seek' location is not a multiple of the 'bs' I use elsewhere.

My question is: Is there a way using dd or any other program/Perl module to write out a blocksize different from the one used to 'seek'?

```
dd if=/dev/ram1 of=/dev/sdb1 seek=2469396480 ibs=1048576 obs=1 count=1
```

As you can see above, while the raw data is read in a 1M block I have to write it out in 1 byte segments because I need to seek to a specific location based on a byte granularity. This makes the write 1/100th as fast.

Is there a workaround? Or is there a way to do this in Perl without using dd?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Does this work better? `dd if=/dev/ram1 seek=2469396480 ibs=1048576 obs=1 > /dev/sdb1`

Comment: Wouldn't that command just write my 1M block to the beginning of /dev/sdb1? I don't get the seek to 2469396480.

Comment: @Nick, you're right. I'll try once more: `dd if=/dev/ram1 ibs=1048576 | dd of=/dev/sdb1/ seek=N obs=M`, where `M` is your output block size and 'N` = 2469396480/M

Comment: What if M is not a factor of 246939648? DD cannot take a decimal. I say this because I tried this one also.

Comment: @vNick this simple approach did have an assumption of a common multiple, or at least that they could be expected to have reasonably high gcd.

Comment: This particular example is bad.  2469396480 is 2^20 * 2355, where 2^20 is 1 MB (1048576).  In this case you'd have `dd if= of= seek=2355 ibs=1048576 obs=1048576 count=1`

Answer (score 0):

This problem is inherent in `dd`. If your desired seek location has no factor of suitable magnitude (big enough for good performance but small enough to use as a buffer size) then you're stuck. This happens among other times when your desired seek location is a large prime.

In this specific case, as [Mark Mann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/689423/mark-mann) pointed out, you *do* have good options: 2469396480 is 2355 blocks of size 1048576, or 1024 blocks of size 2411520, etc... But that's not a generic answer.

To do this generically, you'll want to use something other than `dd`. Fortunately, `dd`'s task is really simple and all you need is the following (in pseudocode... I haven't done much Perl in a while)

```
if = open("/dev/ram1", "r")
of = open("/dev/sdb1", "r+")
seek(of, 2469396480)
loop until you have copied the amount of data you want {
    chunk = read(if, min(chunksize, remaining_bytes_to_copy))
    write(of, chunk)
}
```

It looks like the source of your copy is a ramdisk of some sort. If you really want screaming performance, you might try another method besides reading chunks into a buffer and writing the buffer out to the output file. For example you can `mmap()` the source file and `write()` directly from the mapped address. The OS may (or may not) optimize away one of the RAM-to-RAM copy operations. Note that such methods will be less portable and less likely to be available in high level languages like Perl.